# Windows Kinect SDK + OpenNI Primesense

Tags: c#, c++, kinect, openni

I was just wondering if it is possible to install both Windows Kinect SDK and OpenNI Primesense at the same time, where I don't need to uninstall either of the two when I work on different projects. Any idea is really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [project](https://www.assembla.com/code/kinect-mssdk-openni-bridge/git/nodes) in development that hooks OpenNI into the Kinect SDK.  It sounds like this may meet your requirements.

The Windows Kinect SDK driver and the driver generally used with OpenNI ([SensorKinect](https://github.com/avin2/SensorKinect)) cannot coexist.

Comment: They cannot coexist for multiple reasons, one important reason, a device cannot use multiple drivers.  Would cause havok...